# ARM Cortex behavior on erased flash

Tags: arm, cortex-m, cortex

After erasing the flash of a typical microcontroller with an ARM Cortex, I assume the flash contents to be all `ff`.

**What is the behavior of the microcontroller after reset, especially that of its processor, in this case?**

The only things I am reasonably certain about are these: Upon reset, the inital PC and the initial SP are set to `0xffffffff`.

I am unsure what happens next: Is there an exception because the stack pointer is unaligned? Does the processor fetch an instruction from memory address `0xffffffff`? If the instruction is fetched, is it taken from the two bytes (I think it should be a Thumb instruction because the initial PC has the low bit set) at `0xffffffff` and `0x00000000` or does the instruction fetch access wrap around the "System" section boundary from `0xffffffff` to `0xe0100000`?

Comment: Note that built-in ROM might check these values to be valid (for example NXP chips have a checksum for first few vectors) and just not transfer control to application code.

Comment: I think that this check is a very sensible idea. Some parts - I am specifically thinking of the STM32F4 line - do not seem to have this check but start to execute the "application" in the flash right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core will enter LOCKUP state. This failure is actually architecturally defined (v7M):

> Vector read error at reset, when reading initial PC or SP value
>   Behavior Lockup at priority -1.Lockup address 0xFFFFFFFE

The core will then remain stuck in this state (since it is impossible to fetch from an XN region):

> In most cases, when the processor enters Lockup state, it remains in
>   that state until a reset, such as from a watchdog.

This is in contrast to some of the other lockup states where the error can technically be cleared and the core will just keep trying forever.

I think that the SP being illegal is benign until the stack is used.